# Active Record Associations undefined method 'val' (build,create enabled by has_many,belongs_to)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am quite new to rails and I have a bit of trouble understanding associations. I want to make a fast forum(just the thread - post mechanism nothing else) . My models are generated by :

```
1. rails generate scaffold Forumthread title:string
2. rails generate scaffold Forumpost title:string content:text username:string
```

In my models I added the associations namely:

```
class Forumthread < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :forumposts, dependent: :destroy
end

class Forumpost < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :forumthread
end
```

On the show page of a thread I want to be able to make a forumpost for that thread . I am trying to do it like this : 
view:
      <%= notice %>

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @forumthread.title %>
</p>

<% form_for(@post) do |f| %>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_forumthread_path(@forumthread) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', forumthreads_path %>
```

and controller:

```
def show
    @current_thread = Forumthread.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @post = @current_thread.forumposts.build
  end
```

I didn't get to the create part because it seems it doesn't work just typing `@current_thread.forumposts.build` to create an object. What am I missing ?
I want @post to be an object of type forumpost so I can create with `@current_thread.forumposts.create(forumposts_params)`;

At the moment I get the following error:

```
undefined method `val' for #<Arel::Nodes::BindParam:0x007fe5c0648770>
```

I will happily provide more data if it is requested! .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I remember reading about this error occuring when `foreign_key` is missing (https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/78bd18a90992e3da767cfe492f1bc5d63077da8a) and it looks like this might be your case, since you didn't included it when genereting scaffold for Forumpost. Do you have `forumthread_id` column in your database table for Forumposts? If you don't know what I'm talking about - go to db/schema.rb file and and check if you can see something like:

```
 create_table "forumsposts", force: true do |t|
    #some other fields
    t.integer  "forumthread_id", null: false
    #some other fields
 end
```

If not, you will have to generate and run one more migration adding this missing `foreign_key` to Forumspost. Read about it on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-foreign-key :), run `rails generate migration AddForumthreadIdToForumpost`, put something like the code below in newly created migration file and run `rake db:migrate`:

```
class AddForumthreadIdToForumpost < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :forumposts, :forumthread_id, :integer, null: false
    add_index :forumposts, :forumthread_id
  end
end
```

Comment: yes yes, i know what you are talking about . I will open my laptop in the next few minutes and let you know. I haven't included that column because i thought it will be added by rails :D If what you just said is the true error then it might make sense why it worked the last time I used something like this(i added the column by hand)

Comment: same error. Also i think the content of the change method is added when you make a migration no? because it wasn't added this time. This is odd...

Comment: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts this guy uses reference or something is that mandatory ?

Comment: hmm, did you run "rake db:migrate" at the end? 'reference' is just different way of doing the same thing, but if what I posted didn't help you, then I have no idea what is this about.

Comment: yes yes :)) I did , twice I even added the change by hand and restarted the server twice

Comment: another standard thing to do would be to update gems :) Sorry if this didn't help you, but I'm sure you needed foregin_key there, so at least it's improvement.

Comment: ok i deleted gem.lock ran bundle install again... still the same! :(

Comment: i made another project a couple weeks ago where except what i've written here i wrote resources :articles  do
    resources :comments
  end  is this a must ?

Comment: just `bundle update` would be better, no need to delete gem.lock before that. I don't know who your controller with `create` action looks like, but I would quess, yes - you need to have nested resources in config/routes.rb and those scaffold added them independently. However, I doubt this is causing the error you're getting.

Comment: Basia Madej you were totally right the bugg was from the Active Record i couldn't fix the former project BUT i made a new one. The solution is to add when you generate the model a reference to the forumthread model something like rails g model forumposts title:string content:string references:forumthread

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still working on this issue. But, have you tried `accepts_nested_attributes_for` inside of your model?

```
class Forumthread < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :forumposts, dependent: :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :forum_post
end

class Forumpost < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :forumthread

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :forum_thread
end
```

Comment: Nope :)) it was a while ago . From what I remember I just made a new project and it worked. Thank you for your interest!